# How implement only landscape orientation for tablet and portrait orientation on phone devices?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, phonejs, devextreme

Now I used DevExtreme Mobile 14.1.3 version. And my application on tablet and phone devices not locked orientation now. How can I locked orientation via DevExtreme (phonejs) framework methods or it should be implement via other technologies? Could you please explain me

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score -1):

Open the properties of your mobile project in Visual Studio.

There in `General` tab you'll find `Screen orientation` dropdown.

Select necessary orientation there

[image]

**Edits**

Different orientations for phone and tablet in a single project is not supported. You have to create separate apps for phone and tablet. Since DevExtreme supports sharing code between projects it should not be a big problem.

Comment: Ok, but my question is how locked landscape orientation for tablet and portrait for phone. Your answer locked orientation for all devices

Comment: Oh, I see. It was not clear from your question. Unfortunately, DevExtreme doesn't support this feature. To do so you can create separate projects for Phone and Tablet (as it happens when you generate multi-channel app in VS wizard). Moreover, not sure, but as far as I know, it's impossbile even on Cordova config level. Knowingly for ios you have to create different apps for iPhone and iPad. For Anrdoid, actually, there is no difference between phone and tablet. So separate apps for the rescue. BTW DevExtreme nicely supports sharing code between these projects.

Comment: I've created project for iOS iPhone and set resolution like it describe on your screenshot. It works, after started app resolution  is portrait, but this resolution is not locked.

Comment: Have you build a native package? The orientation lock works only in native package.

Comment: Yes, I've build native package for iOS but orientation not locked on iPhone device

Comment: If you built package and deployed it on your phone correctly it should work. That's exactly what this option does. Maybe you faced with some issues of your particular version of DevExtreme. Then it's better to contact support team. They work extremely fast and give precise answers. BTW: thanks for your down vote of my detailed and correct answer to your question.